# Azure ARM API - optimistic concurrency

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Through the ARM REST API, I want to read a resource (an NSG) modify it and then write it back.  I want the last step (writing it back) to fail if something came along and modified the resource in between my read and my write operation.  Is that possible?  I see there is an ETAG property when I do a GET, perhaps there is some way to utilize it to make the write fail if the resource is modified?

Comment: What's your scenario? I.e. how do you know that the change that happened between your read and write takes precedence over yours?  Could you lock the resource?

Comment: @bmoore-msft my scenario is automating NSG changes (e.g. runbook with webhook).  If two changes occur concurrently, I was hoping there is a way to make one fail and then retry the other with an exponential backoff.

Comment: Ok, but even in that case it's at best a race, right?  If I could "lock" the resource for the period of time I'm working on it (which won't actually work, but the idea is the same) - someone could come along immediate after your write and make the change they wanted to make anyway...

Comment: @bmoore-msft I wasn't quite specific enough.  It isn't a race if part of my retry logic (if someone else modified the list) is to first re-read the list, add the pending change again, and then attempt to save again.

Comment: Understood - I'm not trying to be provocative, just want to see if I can wrap my head around the scenario and see if there's a platform gap here.  There are some properties that cannot be changed once set, but for everything else if you "declare" this is what you want, then that's what the platform will give you - the current state of the resource isn't taken into account.  You *could* GET the current state and do the comparison on your own - that would be pretty simple in REST - would that work in your case?

Comment: @bmoore-msft thanks for following up! Your suggestion still has a gap.  If I overwrite another change (which happened between reading and writing)  I can't make an API call to see if things are in the desired state because I can't see the change I overwrote.  That is why I want the call to fail if I overwrite another change (so I can read again, apply changes again, and attempt to write again).  Thanks!

Comment: FYI, I added a request in the feedback forum:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/18987883-add-support-for-optimistic-concurrency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I known, Azure Table Storage has the `ETag` in `ITableEntity` which is used for optimistic concurrency during updates. While the Azure REST API [Network Security Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network/networksecuritygroups) about `etag`:

> A unique read-only string that changes whenever the resource is updated.

I have tried to leverage [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) and [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com) to simulate the concurrent update operations on my NSG, and I found that there is no concurrency control on the update operation, the configurations would be overrided by the later request.

Per my understanding, there is no build-in feature for you to handle optimistic concurrency. For NSG, I assumed that you would not frequently modify it. So, I think you could try to limit the permission for a few people to update your NSG, or you could build your custom REST API for updating NSG, and get the latest NSG info, then compare the `etag` with your prior `etag` to determine that whether the NSG is modified before you update it. Also, you could add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/14997987-network-security-group).

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I am automating NSG changes with a runbook and I am looking for a built-in way to serialize changes.  Runbooks don't have a built-in way to accomplish this so I was hoping the ARM REST API had something since I noticed the e-tag property.  Your manual e-tag comparison suggestion doesn't really help since I know the e-tag will be different after since I am modifying the NSG, so it will always be different.  I can build something to handle my situation, but I was hoping I didn't have to!